# Отдельная страница для каждого товара ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Делаю учебный сайт на ASP.NET MVC, в котором на главной должен быть список товаров и отдельные страницы на каждый товар, на которые ведут ссылки из списка. Не пойму, как это осуществить. Сейчас есть страница списка, пробовал на странице списка вызывать

```
@model IEnumerable <TestParser.Domain.Entities.Product>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List";
}

@foreach(var p in Model)
{
<div class="item">
    <h3>

        @Html.ActionLink(p.Name, "Single", "Product", p.ProdID, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
    </h3>
    @foreach(var prise in p.PriseParseResults)
    {
        <p>@prise.Result</p>
    }
</div>
}
```

а в контроллере соответственно

```
public ViewResult Single(int? prodID)
    {
        Product prod = repository.Products.Single(p => p.ProdID == prodID);
        return View(prod);
    }
```

но при таком подходе в контроллере выдается исключение

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Последовательность не содержит элементов

Comment: Так и в чем вопрос то? У Вас есть вся информация почему не работает..

Comment: дело в том, что элементы есть, на странице со списком ведь они выводятся, но контроллер их почему то не находит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если проверить программу дебагером, видно, что аргумент, который передается в метод имеет значение null, а ссылка, генерируемая этим методом не содержит тела запроса.
Вызов метода @Html.ActionLink должен быть построен следующим образом:

```
@Html.ActionLink(p.Name, "Single", "Product", new { prodID = p.ProdID }, null)
```

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно,  что на момент вызова метода Single, свойство на объекте Вашего репозитория,  которое должно возвращать список всех продуктов,  возвращает пустую коллекцию,  т. е. Вы пытаетесь получить продукт с заданным id из коллекции,  которая не содержит элементов. Перед вызовом метода Single,  убедитесь, что Вы корректно инициализировали репозиторий. Например,  код инициализации можно поместить в конструктор контроллера,  содержащего метод Single. Приведите весь код контроллера, тогда ответ на Ваш вопрос можно уточнить.

Comment: 'public class ProductController : Controller
    {
        private IProductRepository repository;
        public ProductController(IProductRepository productRepository)
        {
            this.repository = productRepository;
        }
        public ViewResult List()
        {
            return View(repository.Products);
        }

        public ViewResult Single(int? prodID)
        {
            Product prod = repository.Products.Single(p => p.ProdID == prodID);
            return View(prod);
        }
    }'

Comment: В вашем проекте используются IoC-контейнер? Судя по всему, где-то в проекте есть класс, ответственный за инстанциирование объекта, который передаётся по ссылке в конструктор контроллера. КТо создаёт объект типа IProductRepository?

Comment: Другой вариант - где-то в коде должен быть перегружен метод Initialize(): `protected override void Initialize(IProductContext productContext)`. Ищите ошибку инициализации репозитория в одном из этих мест. В любом случае, где-то создаётся репозиторий, и создаётся некорректно. Т.к. иначе Вы бы, скорее всего, получили `NullReferenceException` вместо `InvalidOperationException`.

Comment: в проекте используется ninject, я так понимаю, что он и отвечает за инстанцирование. вот его код

Comment: public class NinjectControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
    {
        private IKernel ninjectKernel;
        public NinjectControllerFactory()
        {
            ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel();
            AddBindings();
        }

        protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
        {
            return controllerType == null
                ? null
                : (IController)ninjectKernel.Get(controllerType);
        }

Comment: private void AddBindings()
        {
            
            ninjectKernel.Bind<IProductRepository>().To<EFProductRepository>();
            ninjectKernel.Bind<IPriseParseResultRepository>().To<EFPriseParseResultRepository>();

Comment: @ klutch1991 а есть ли способы решить задачу как то по другому? как вообще это должно делаться правильно? в книгах и интернете пока что ответа не нашел.

Comment: Всё делается правильно. Скорее всего, ошибка в коде репозиториев. Как Вы заполняете коллекцию PriseParseResults для кадого объекта продукта?

Comment: у меня отдельный репозиторий для PriseParseResults public class EFPriseParseResultRepository : IPriseParseResultRepository
    {
        private TestParserDBEntities context = new TestParserDBEntities();
        public IQueryable<PriseParseResult> PriseParseResults
        {
            get
            {
                return context.PriseParseResults;
            }
            set
            {
                context.PriseParseResults.AddRange(PriseParseResults);
            }
        }
        
    }

Comment: Кто-то должен заниматься передачей parse results в объекты продуктов